# How to preserve the logind session in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, systemd, alsa, logind

I got audio working in Arch Linux without problems yesterday, but at some point it stopped working again:

```
$ alsamixer 
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
$ vlc foo.mp4
...
[0x7f1388006be8] alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "default": No such file or directory
```

`alsamixer` runs fine as `root`, so it seems to be a permission problem. All the audio devices are owned by `root:audio`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/snd
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       80 Aug  6 22:54 by-path
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  7 Aug  6 22:54 controlC0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 10 Aug  6 22:54 controlC1
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  6 Aug  6 22:54 hwC0D0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  9 Aug  6 22:54 hwC1D0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  5 Aug  6 22:54 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  4 Aug  6 22:54 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  3 Aug  6 22:54 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  2 Aug  6 22:54 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  8 Aug  6 22:54 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  1 Aug  6 22:54 seq
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 33 Aug  6 22:54 timer
$ getfacl /dev/snd/*
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/snd/by-path
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# file: dev/snd/controlC0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/controlC1
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/hwC0D0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/hwC1D0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D2c
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/seq
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/timer
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::---
```

I'm *not* in the `audio` group, as recommended by the [ALSA instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ALSA#Installation):

```
$ groups
wheel users
```

A [discussion](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk%3aAdvanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#user_in_audio_group) pointed me to an [explanation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Supplementary_information) of why adding the group is unnecessary and sometimes harmful. From there the [user groups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_Groups#User_groups) info said

> None of these groups is needed for standard desktop permissions like sound, 3D, printing, mounting, etc. as long as the *`logind`* session isn't broken.

Following directions to [session permission troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_Troubleshooting#Session_permissions), I finally found a discrepancy - it says the output of `loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID` should contain `Remote=no` and `Active=yes`, but I get the following:

```
$ loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID
ControlGroupHierarchy=/user
ResetControllers=cpu
NAutoVTs=6
KillExcludeUsers=root
KillUserProcesses=no
IdleHint=yes
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
InhibitDelayMaxUSec=5s
HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
IdleAction=ignore
IdleActionUSec=30min
PreparingForShutdown=no
PreparingForSleep=no
```

From there I found info on [preserving the session](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc#Preserving_the_session), which doesn't seem to be applicable - my `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` is unmodified since the installation:

```
$ ls -l /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Oct 31  2012 /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
```

SLiM seems to be running fine:

```
$ systemctl status slim.service
slim.service - SLiM Simple Login Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slim.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2013-08-10 00:00:39 CEST
 Main PID: 258 (slim)
   CGroup: name=systemd:/system/slim.service
           ├─ 258 /usr/bin/slim -nodaemon
           ├─ 292 /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp vt07 -auth /var/run/slim.auth
           ├─ 416 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
           ├─ 418 awesome
           ├─ 423 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
           ├─ 472 xscreensaver -no-splash
           ├─ 479 firefox
           ├─ 481 java -Xmx192M -jar /usr/share/java/jedit/jedit.jar -reuseview
           ├─ 483 pidgin
           ├─ 485 xterm
           ├─ 500 bash
           ├─ 581 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
           ├─ 641 xterm
           ├─ 643 bash
           ├─1006 git gui
           ├─1007 wish /usr/lib/git-core/git-gui --
           ├─1367 dbus-launch --autolaunch e943bbb765d74fceb0393a55ceebfd1d --binary-syntax --close-stderr
           ├─1368 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
           ├─1403 ekiga
           ├─1405 /usr/lib/GConf/gconfd-2
           ├─1476 thunar
           ├─1478 /usr/lib/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
           └─1589 systemctl status slim.service
```

**What do I need to do to fix the logind session, and thus (presumably) the audio permissions?**

Comment: [TheAudioGroup](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup) says: "The ConsoleKit daemon automatically switches access to the audio device according to the currently logged in user. It does so by setting access rights to the sound device nodes (i e everything under /dev/snd/* ). You can verify that by downloading the acl package, then running the "`getfacl /dev/snd/*`" terminal command, it should list the current logged in user as having read and write access."

Comment: @CL. Nope, see updated answer.

Comment: That `loginctl` ouptut looks wrong in more ways than just a non-active session. How are you logging in and starting X?

Comment: @jasonwryan Could you be a bit more specific? I followed the Arch wiki to [set up X, SLiM and awesome](http://l0b0.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/awesomely-slim-linux-desktop-setup/). Some configuration is linked from there.

Comment: Your output should [look like this](http://sprunge.us/BjLW); I'd say slim is b0rking your session...

Comment: Can you add the status of the slim.service to your post: `systemctl status slim.service`?

Comment: @jasonwryan You were right! Would you mind posting the SLiM session hint as an answer?

Comment: I think you should post your answer; I just pointed you at the likely cause, I can't claim any credit for actually solving it (other than seeing Slim do this sort of thing before) :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `login_cmd` as [@jasonwryan hinted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85788/how-to-preserve-the-logind-session-in-arch-linux?noredirect=1#comment128049_85788); I should have kept the original value rather than following the [SLiM + GNOME keyring][7] on GNOME > 2.30 configuration recommendation:

```
$ grep login_cmd /etc/slim.conf
# login_cmd           exec /bin/sh - ~/.xinitrc %session
# login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session
login_cmd           exec dbus-launch /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session >~/.xsession-errors 2>&1
```

After reverting to `login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session`, I now get more sensible session info:

```
$ loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID
Id=c1
Timestamp=Fri 2013-08-09 22:30:28 CEST
TimestampMonotonic=11871667
DefaultControlGroup=systemd:/user/1000.user/c1.session
VTNr=7
Display=:0.0
Remote=no
RemoteUser=root
Service=slim
Leader=260
Audit=0
Type=x11
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
KillProcesses=no
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
Name=username
```

This actually fixed the primary problem - `vlc` is able to play videos if I manually set it to use the first HDA Intel audio device.